# Can I install a Gnu/Linux distro on the Hd using another PC and put it back on my computer?

Tags: system-installation, hard-disk, hardware

I can't access my computer's BIOS, because the keyboard doesn't work at boot time ....

And I want to install a Gnu/Linux distribution, so I will have to use another computer to install.

My question is:

Will the HD already be recognized when I put it back on my computer?

Comment: It may depend on the distro, but it should work. (but not one of those super optimising ones, that strip out everything that is not needed.)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, it would work.

I recently took the SSD out of my old x220 laptop, put it on my brand new desktop AMD Ryzen 5 2600X based and Debian just boot up with no problem.

Just pay attention to CPU architecture (if destination computer's processor only supports 32 bits, then do not install a 64 bits OS).

Comment: Agree. Also ARM vs x86. etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about now days, although a few years ago I did that. I had two boxes where the Processor was same family and no raid arrays. I think that I was using Fedora Core 5 or something like that.

I would be more interested in your keyboard which is not working at boot time. Usb? PS/2? If Usb, find a PS/2 and see it that works; or try another Usb port. If PS/2 give a Usb a try.

todh

Comment: I use usb. And I think that the ps2 input doesn't work, when I put a ps2 keyboard the lights flash, but the buttons don't work!